# Appending pandas dataframes in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The problem with the code below is that `df` is not appended by new DataFrame. When I `print` the shape it is still `(1,6)`. How can I fix it?

```
columns = ['name', 'precision', 'recall', 'gmean', 'f1', 'mse']
df_SMOTE = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns )
df_ENN = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns )
df_Ensemble = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns )

for name, model in zip(names, [rfc, knc, lr, svc, dtc, xgbc, cbc, lgbc]):
    for X, y, df in [(X_smote, y_smote, df_SMOTE), (X_enn, y_enn, df_ENN), (X_smote, y_smote, df_Ensemble)]:
        learner = Learner(model, X, y)
        learner()
        precision, recall, gmean, f1, mse = learner.get_metrics()
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'name': [name], 'precision': [precision], 'recall': [recall], 'gmean': [gmean], 'f1': [f1], 'mse': [mse]})], ignore_index=True)
        
        print(df.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be faster if you collected each individual dataframe in a list and then did the `concat` after.  Sort of like this:

```
columns = ["name", "precision", "recall", "gmean", "f1", "mse"]
dfs = []
for i in range(100):
    dfs.append(
        pd.DataFrame(
            data=[
                (f"n{i}", f"p{i}", f"r{i}", f"g{i}", f"f{i}", f"m{i}")
                for i in np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=(5,))
            ],
            columns=columns,
        )
    )
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```